(nativescript) Utils.android.getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission('storage') always return false
Android manifest
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Emulator version
_osVersion: "11"
_sdkVersion: "30"

Nativescript version
"@nativescript/core": "~8.6.0"

check permission always return false
Utils.android.getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission('storage')


ancient ideas checkSelfPermission returning false even if Permission is granted not working anymore
The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:remove" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.


and, of course, any attempt to write produced error
  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/2024-06-06-11:08:38.json: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

any fresh ideas, please
